# (Show more/Show less)For only one <td> in table in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have table and I want to use show more/ show less text `pos.report`. currently when I click show more for one `<td>` it show more for all `<td>` in the table.

**.Html**

```
 <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let pos of procedureOrderList; let i = index">
              <td>{{pos.investigationName}}</td>
              <td>{{pos.investigationDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
              <td>{{pos.released_DT | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
              <td> <ng-container *ngIf="pos.report">
                  {{(show) ? pos.report : pos.report | slice:0:50}}             
                 <a *ngIf="pos.report.length > 0;" (click)="show = !show" > ...{{ show ? '[Show less]': '[Show More]' }}</a>
              </ng-container>
              </td>                    
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

**.ts**

`show = false;`

Comment: Put the 'show' property on whatever class/interface 'pos' is.

Comment: do you mean to put 'show' in <tr>? @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: @Hamda https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wk1l4p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html you need kind of this.

Comment: No I meant put it in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to GaurangDhorda's method, you could also extend the model you're using to include 'show' as a property.

So assuming that `pos` is of type `Pos`, defined something like this:

```js
interface Pos {
  investigationName: string;
  investigationDate: date;
  release_DT: date;
  report: string;
}
```

... then what you can do is extend this interface (or class) and provide it with the 'show' property like this:

```js
interface ShowablePos extends Pos {
  show: boolean;
}
```

Then the trick is that when you get your Pos instances (for example, from an API), you use a `map` call to transform them into ShowablePos instances:

```js
posApi.getProcedureOrderList()
  .pipe(map( posList => {
    // each pos is show=false by default
    return posList.map(pos => ({ ...pos, show: false }))
  }))
  .subscribe(...)
```

Then the only change you need to make to your HTML is to refer to `pos.show` instead of a global `show`.

```html
<td>{{pos.investigationName}}</td>
<td>{{pos.investigationDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
<td>{{pos.released_DT | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
<td>
  <ng-container *ngIf="pos.report">
    {{(pos.show) ? pos.report : pos.report | slice:0:50}}
    <a *ngIf="pos.report.length > 0;" (click)="pos.show = !pos.show" > ...{{ pos.show ? '[Show less]': '[Show More]' }}</a>
  </ng-container>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo** in this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wk1l4p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Basically you need to assign index i value to your show property and according to show and i value you can display show more or show less only for clicked td element only.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let pos of procedureOrderList; let i = index">
      <td>{{pos.investigationName}}</td>
      <td>{{pos.investigationDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{pos.released_DT | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>
        <ng-container *ngIf="pos.report">
          {{(show) ? pos.report : pos.report | slice:0:50}}
             <a *ngIf="pos.report.length > 0;" (click)="((show = i ))"> 
                    ...{{ (( show === i)) ? '[Show less]': '[Show More]' }}</a>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: side effect of this workflow -- which does solve the problem by the way -- is that you can only show one row at a time. so if you "show" row 1 and then click "show" on row 2, row 1 will stop showing. this may or may not be what the OP wants, the question doesn't specify.